# Integer range suspension in prolog

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I have the following query:

```
?- Remainder :: 0..8, Qoutient #:: 0..Dividened,
   Dividened #= Qoutient * 9 + Remainder, Dividened = 12.
```

As you can see I have an integer suspension `Qoutient #:: 0..Dividened`, and try to clear the value of the `Dividend` at the end. However, I get the following error:

> ```
> instantiation fault in Qoutient #:: 0 .. Dividened
> ```

So how can I solve the problem in Eclipse CLP?

Comment: I am not sure why you call this a "suspension", you should probably say "variable".

Comment: @jschimpf thanks for your consideration. I thought the `#` sign likes the `$` is used for the suspension. Is n't it?

Comment: In ECLiPSe, "suspension" has a very narrow technical definition (a handle for a delayed subgoal, see http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/suspensions). Only remotely related to what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write `Quotient#>=0, Quotient#=<Dividend`, but there is actually no need to give any a-priori bounds on that variable at all.  Simply use

```
?- Remainder :: 0..8, Dividend #= Quotient * 9 + Remainder, Dividend = 12.
Remainder = 3
Dividend = 12
Quotient = 1
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

You may want to generalize this for arbitrary Divisors and package the whole thing into an auxiliary predicate, such as

```
divmod(Dividend, Divisor, Quotient, Remainder) :-
        0 #=< Remainder, Remainder #=< Divisor-1,
        Dividend #= Quotient*Divisor + Remainder.
```

Then your query becomes

```
?- divmod(D, 9, Q, R), D = 12.
D = 12
Q = 1
R = 3
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```